# my magic mouse is sluggish and hangs sometime when I try to move it

Tags: macos, bluetooth, mouse

I have 2 Magic Mice, Mouses.whatever.. One runs on 2 AA batteries and the other one is rechargeable. I use the 2-AA one when I'm recharging the other.
Recently the rechargeable mouse has started functioning strangely. The movement is jumpy and it seems to stick at times. It's hard to do fine movements. I cleaned the visible sensor used for tracking but it had no effect. If I switch to my old 2 battery mouse it works fine. What can cause one Bluetooth mouse to work and another one not? They both worked fine about a week ago when I had to charge one.

Do the System Preferences settings apply for any mouse being used or are they mouse-specific.

Comment: Did you tried to unpair the problematic one? Try to go to the Bluetooth settings and remove the mouse and pair it again.

Comment: Well, it seems this problem has fixed itself.  I think I may have inadvertently done what you suggested but I can't be sure.  I just replaced the good mouse with the bad one and now they both work the same.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Cat hair. Don't know how you get it out of the seal units.

Comment: Anyone found a solution yet? I did EVERYthing I find in the net. mouse is still sluggish...

Answer (score 1):

There is a known problem with Bluetooth being interfered with by WiFi and especially by USB3 devices. This seems to be a particular problem with the 2018 Mac Minis. [See this discussion.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8640793)

What Mac model?

Comment: My iMac is a 2010 model so no USB3.  Also, as I said in the question. one wireless mouse works fine. The other one doesn't.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Had the same issue with Magic Mouse and a Mac mini 2018. Mouse was terribly lagging, even during scroll. The same mouse worked well on my MBP. Moved the Wi-Fi. router away, the issue is gone. Thanks for the tip.